# python rio_tiler : failed to select the wanted color band

Tags: python

I'm trying to select a band from a tif image with rio_tiler/preview function.
But I don't understand how it works, I get always the same image.

I tried from the example https://cogeotiff.github.io/rio-tiler/examples/Using-rio-tiler/

```
from rio_tiler.io import Reader
from rio_tiler.models import ImageData

from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, imshow, subplots

src_path = "https://njogis-imagery.s3.amazonaws.com/2020/cog/I7D16.tif"
with Reader(src_path) as src:
    info = src.info()
    print(info.json(exclude_none=True))
```

gives me

```
{"bounds": [-74.3095632062702, 40.603994417539994, -74.29151245384847, 40.61775082944064], "minzoom": 14, "maxzoom": 19, "band_metadata": [["b1", {}], ["b2", {}], ["b3", {}], ["b4", {}]], "band_descriptions": [["b1", ""], ["b2", ""], ["b3", ""], ["b4", ""]], "dtype": "uint16", "nodata_type": "None", "colorinterp": ["red", "green", "blue", "undefined"], "width": 5000, "height": 5000, "count": 4, "driver": "GTiff", "overviews": [2, 4, 8, 16]}
```

So 4 bands : red, green, blue and undefined.

Now I would like to display only the red band then the green one, then the blue one...
I believe from the previous info that red -> index=1, green -> index=2, blue -> index=3, right ?

```
with Reader(src_path) as src:
    nir_band1 = src.preview(indexes=1)

    # Data is in Uint16 so we need to rescale
    nir_band1.rescale(((nir_band1.data.min(), nir_band1.data.max()),))

print(nir_band1.data.shape)
print(nir_band1.data.dtype)
imshow(nir_band1.data_as_image())
```

which gives me a blue image, and if I try with "indexes=2" or "indexes=3", I get the same blue image.
"indexes=4" gives me some greeny image. Don't know why.

Then if I try :

```
src.preview(indexes=(4,3,1))
```

that gives me a red one, but don't get why.

I also tried with

```
src.preview(expression="(b4-b1)/(b4+b1)")
src.preview(expression="(b4-b2)/(b4+b2)")
src.preview(expression="(b4-b3)/(b4+b3)")
```

but still don't get how it works.

Thank so much for your help.